# postfix 'd+0' in Fortran real literal expressions

Tags: floating-point, fortran, notation, double-precision

Does anyone knwow what the postfix "**d+0**" means in the assignments to M1, M2 and M4 below or is there any resource on the web or a book where one is very likely to find this information?

---

```
      subroutine plot( t, x, p, q, nga, nt, wron, 
     &                 ngq, gq, ngaq1, ngaq2, gaq, rwh, iwh )
        implicit none

        integer*4 nga, nt, ngq, ngaq1, ngaq2, iwh(*)

        real*8 t, x(*), p(*), q(*), wron(nga,*),
     &         gq(ngq,*), gaq(ngaq1,ngaq2,*), rwh(*)

        real*8 M1, M2, M3, M4, mr, mst, h3, Tc
        integer*8 iflag

c       DISCRETIZE1( Tc, rwh, iwh )

        M1 = 0.1362d+0
        M2 = 0.09806d+0
        M3 = M1 + M2
        M4 = 0.236d+0

        mr = M1*x(1) + M2*x(2) + M3*x(3) + M4*x(4)
        mst =  M1*q(1) + M2*q(2) + M4*q(3)

        call mess3( t, x, h3, p, q, rwh, iwh, iflag )

        write (10,100) t, x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), Tc, h3, mr-mst
100     format( e20.10, 7(1x,e20.10) ) 

  end
```

Comment: @Deduplicator Why do you remove the `real` tag? And why there are another two recently changed Fortran questions with the real tag with some edit revoked within the grace period?

Comment: @Vla Don't know about the other two, and this one *might* have been premature. Should have let the meta-discussion go on some more first...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means "double precision" and the +0 means 10 to the zeroth power (zero is the exponent).

Here's a quote from [first reference](http://www.obliquity.org/computer/fortran/datatype.html) I could find:

> A number stored in a computer is
> limited in magnitude and precision.
> The limits depend on the particular
> computer. Thus, a REAL number has only
> a certain number of significant
> digits. If more significant digits are
> required for a calculation, then
> DOUBLE PRECISION numbers must be used.
> A DOUBLE PRECISION constant is written
> in the same exponential form as a
> single precision REAL constant except
> with a D instead of an E separating
> the mantissa from the exponent.

And here is a quote from a better reference, [www.fortran.com](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-4.html#sh-4.2.1), specifically the F77 standard.

> 4.5.2 Double Precision Constant.
>
> The forms of a double precision
> constant are:
>
> 1. Basic real constant
>    followed by a double precision
>    exponent
> 2. Integer constant followed by
>    a double precision exponent
>
> The value
> of a double precision constant is the
> product of the constant that precedes
> the D and the power of ten indicated
> by the integer following the D. The
> integer constant part of form (2) may
> be written with more digits than a
> processor will use to approximate the
> value of the constant.

Comment: o__O wow thanks for the immediate reply, I was looking for chat rooms/channels for Fortran newbies but you answered my question even before I had time to decide which IRC client to use!!