# fortran basic help 'd' operator

Tags: fortran, fortran90

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [postfix 'd+0' in Fortran real literal expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913816/postfix-d0-in-fortran-real-literal-expressions)

I have this code line in Fortran 90:

```
OVERN2 = 1.d+0/DBLE(FLOAT(NMODE2))
```

`NMODE2` is an integer, `OVERN2` is a `REAL*8`.

Can you please explain to me what this line does? I don't understand the `.d+0/` part?
if you can also translate that to C or any other easier language.

Comment: This looks like the same question as 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913816/postfix-d0-in-fortran-real-literal-expressions

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520819/what-does-real8-mean/10521611 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263157/getting-double-precision-in-fortran-90-using-intel-11-1-compiler/5267505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.d+0` is just a double precision literal in scientific notation, i.e. 1.0e0 or just 1.0.

In C it would be:

```
double overn2 = 1.0 / (double)nmode2;
```

Comment: For super clarity: 1.d+0 == 1.0d+0 == 1.0d0 == REAL(1, 8)

Comment: Not necesarilly REAL(1, 8)!!! In g77 it is REAL(1, 2) AFAIK.

Comment: I.e. kind numbers are not portable and one has to inquire for them.

Comment: aaaa!! 
thank you all!! most appreciated